# SQL string search among multiple joined records

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

This is in SQLite.

I have two tables, X and Y. X has an 'id' field. Y has a 'tag' field and a foreign key 'xid' mapped to X.id.

Let's say we want to process a list of strings, for example ["abacus", "baritone", "custard"]. I want to select each record **N** in X where Y contains all of these records: {"abacus", **N**.id}, {"baritone", **N**.id}, {"custard", **N**.id}.

If possible it would also be nice to handle substrings so that we can get the same result from the list ["aba", "tone", "star"], but that might be asking too much.

I might not have explained very well so I am willing to clarify the question where required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`.  For the first problem:

```
select y.id
from y
where y.tag in ('abacus', 'baritone', 'custard')
group by y.id
having count(*) = 3;
```

The second is a bit more complicated because you could have tags like "malabar" or "semitone" or "astaroth".  So:

```
select y.id
from y
group by y.id
having sum(case when y.tag like '%aba%' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when y.tag like '%tone%' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when y.tag like '%star%' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Comment: Brilliant, I checked your first solution and it works perfectly.

Sorry, I misled you in the second bit... I was wrong to say "same result".  If "malabar" or "semitone" or "astaroth" exist then those are acceptable results from the query. Is the solution simply to remove the where clause?

Comment: Also, you're fast!

Comment: @matt_rule . . . The `where` clause is gone.